# button click to redirect to a form in Vaadin

Tags: java, liferay, vaadin

I am trying to write code that displays a button that when clicked will redirect me to a form in Vaadin. Can you help with this? Here is my form1 code. My goal is that when subscribeBtn is pressed I will be redirected to form2.

```
 public class AchrefliferayApplication extends Application {

    @Autowired
    ArticleService articleService;


    public void init() {
        Article article;

        Window w = new Window("Subscribe Newsletter");
        setMainWindow(w);
        w.setContent(new VerticalLayout());

        Button subscribeBtn = new Button("saisi");

        w.addComponent(subscribeBtn);


    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a ClickListener to the button. In the handler, create a new Window that holds the Form2 object (setContent), and use setModal on the Window.